# Drop rows with contradicting information from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different dataframes, one with all the user information, and one with the recorded information from the users. Some of the information in the users dataframe contradicts each other, which is why I want to remove those users from both dataframes. I'm doing this for a school project, and they give the hint that I should use a for loop, but I can't figure out how to use this with the different dataframes.

In the part before this, I had to identify these users and put them into a list:

> Inspect the df_users data frame. You will notice that for some users there is more than one row. For example, some users appear to have indicated multiple computer settings. Since at this point we cannot ask those users which settings they have actually used, we will discard those users and the corresponding trials.
>
> Identify which users have entered contradicting information, i.e. both right and left handed or using different computer settings, and assign them to a list wrong_users.
>
> Hint: for these users there will be multiple rows in the data frame.

```
#// BEGIN_TODO [ORG_3f] Find the wrong users (1 point)

wrong_users = [df_users[df_users.duplicated(subset='user', keep=False)]['user']]

#// END_TODO [ORG_3f]

wrong_users
```

which resulted in this

```
[25905    1598
 25920    1598
 29006    1017
 29019    1017
 Name: user, dtype: int64]
```

Now I need to remove these users from both the `df_users` and the `df_trials` dataframes.

> Discard the rows from df_users and df_trials corresponding to the users which have entered contradicting information.
>
> Hint: use a for loop and remove the rows corresponding to those users one by one.

I've already tried multiple different methods, some of which I'm still using to look for the right way to select the right rows.

Some of the things I've tried are:

```
df_trials[df_trials['user'] == df_users[df_users.duplicated('user', keep=False)][['user']]]
```

```
df_trials[['user']] == df_users[df_users.duplicated('user', keep=False)][['user']]
```

```
for n in df_users:
   df_trials[df_trials['user'] == df_users[df_users.duplicated('user')]]
        df_users.drop_duplicates(subset='user')
```

```
for user in df_trials:
    df_trials[df_trials['user'] == wrong_users].drop()
```

But I think it's pretty clear that I don't know where to begin with this. If someone can help me I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you can use [pd.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and negate it to only keep user that are not in your `wrong_users` dataframe. It's a good idea to avoid for-loops where you can, as it defeats the purpose of vectorized operations in pandas. You can use a tilde `~` to negate the `isin()` expression. Here's a complete example.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create dummy dataframe with (some) duplicated users
all_users = pd.DataFrame({
    "user": ["user1", "user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user4"],
    "setting": ["setting1", "setting2", "setting1", "setting1", "setting1", "setting2"]
})
print(all_users)
```

Which gives:

```
    user   setting
0  user1  setting1
1  user1  setting2
2  user2  setting1
3  user3  setting1
4  user4  setting1
5  user4  setting2
```

As you can see, `user1` and `user4` have duplicate entries. Let's identify those, as you've done:

```
# Identify duplicated users
wrong_users = all_users[all_users.duplicated(subset="user", keep=False)]
print(wrong_users)
```

This correctly identifies our duplicates:

```
    user   setting
0  user1  setting1
1  user1  setting2
4  user4  setting1
5  user4  setting2
```

Let's keep only users from our `all_users` dataframe that are *not* in `wrong_users`:

```
# Keep only users who are not in "wrong_users"
correct_users = all_users.loc[~all_users.user.isin(wrong_users.user)]
print(correct_users)
```

Which yields non-duplicated entries:

```
    user   setting
2  user2  setting1
3  user3  setting1
```

---

**EDIT:** `pd.isin()` works with dataframe columns (as in my example), but also with plain lists (as in your question):

```
list_of_wrong_users = all_users[all_users.duplicated(subset="user", keep=False)].user.unique().tolist()  # ['user1', 'user4']
correct_users = all_users.loc[~all_users.user.isin(list_of_wrong_users)]
```